# WireMock: Stubbing - How get object "testClient"?

Tags: wiremock

I want to test http request/response. So I use WireMock.

I want to stub response for specific request:
Here code:

```
 public class WireMockPersons {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);

    @Test
public void exactUrlOnly() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                .withBody("Hello world!")));

    assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing").statusCode(), is(200));
    assertThat(testClient.get("/some/thing/else").statusCode(), is(404));
}
```

Code is not compile because no object **testClient**. How I can get **testClient** object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testClient` is your client library for the API you are mocking.

Looks like you have copied directly from the examples which are indicative only.

Replace `testClient` with the HTTP library of your choosing, for example `HttpClient`.

```
String url = "http://localhost:8089/some/thing";
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpEntity entity = client.execute(get).getEntity();
    return  EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to call " + url, e);
}
```