# WireMock: Stubbing - Not able to implement "AssertThat" method correctly

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm struggling to create a simple stub. I've been following the wiremock tutorial online but have had no success on the issue im facing. Particularly, the "Get" method in the AssertMethod is giving me a lot of issues. I don't know how to resolve it.

```
public class WeatherApplicationTest {


    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule();
    public  WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(); //No-args constructor will start on port 8080, no HTTPS



    @BeforeClass
    public  void setUpClass() {
        wireMockServer.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public  void tearDownClass() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }


    @Test
    public void statusMessage() throws IOException{

        wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withStatus(200)
        .withStatusMessage("Everything is fine")
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "Text/Plain")));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:" + wireMockServer.port() + "/some/thing");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        assertThat(response.GET("/some/thing").statusCode(), is(200));


}
}
```

I'm getting an error on the following line:

```
    assertThat(response.GET("/some/thing").statusCode(), is(200));
```

The GET method is underlined in Red.

Please Help!

Comment: The red means there's a compile-time error (or, less-likely, you have set up compile-time restrictions you are breaking).  What does it say when you actually mouse over the red line (or otherwise check your errors)?

Comment: Hi @Ironcache, it basically says the method "GET" is non-existence in the HTTP Response class.

Comment: So I'd listen to it; does the `GET` method exist in `HttpResponse` [class](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true)?

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43648745/1601729), which illustrates how to do what you want, I believe.

Comment: Cheers @Ironcache, but I had a look, but I'm struggling on how to incorporate that into my Assert method

Comment: I posted an answer to try and help a little further.  If it does not help with the issue, feel free to leave a comment on it.

Comment: The WireMockServer stuff is redundant if you're using the rule. I'd recommend getting rid of all that for simplicity's sake. WireMockRule is a subclass of WireMockServer, so you can call all the same methods against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WireMock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/) doesn't do a great job of outlining how to connect with it (but, in their defense, it's not really in their slice of the pie).

As I eluded to in the comments, `HttpResponse` does not contain a `GET()` method, which is why you're getting the "red underline" (IE: error).

So we know we are looking to make an assertion against the status code.  If we look at the [Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true) of the `HttpResponse` class, there is the `StatusLine` class that can be retrieved from `getStatusLine()` of `HttpResponse`, and the [Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html) of that class shows that it contains a `getStatusCode()` method.  Combining this information into your answer, the assertion needs to be updated to:

```
assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), is(200));
```

In addition, as pointed out by Tom in the comments, remove the `WireMockServer` (as well as the `start/stop` and `getPort()` calls; you can get the port from your rule.  And the `stubFor(...)` method should be called statically (not as a part of the rule).

Comment: Hi @Ironcache, Really appreciate your help! However, when I try to run this JUnit file, by right clicking on the file and selecting "Test File", i get the following error "Expected is: <200> bur: was <404>" I get directed to the following line of code as the source of the error: assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), is(200));

Comment: So you're progressing here.  I do not know much about the utility, so I can't provide too much specific support here, but what that means is that instead of an "OK" HTTP response (200), you're getting a "Not Found" HTTP response (404).  Basically it isn't finding your WireMock.  A couple things to try: 1) change `wireMockRule.stubFor(...)` to just `stubFor(...)` (IE: don't associate it with the rule); 2) remove the unused `WireMockServer` object and its start/stop calls (get the port from the `WireMockRule` object, which itself extends `WireMockServer`).

Comment: As an extension of the first point, ensure your import looks like this: `import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;`

Comment: Thank you @Ironcahce, your advise helped!

Answer (score 0):

My contribution to this question: this Java test runs without exceptions, both in the IDE and in Maven as well, and, moreover with the other tests, because at the end, it shuts down the mock server, and doesn't make any conflicts with other servers running in the other tests.

```
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import wiremock.org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import wiremock.org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import wiremock.org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import wiremock.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class KatharsisControllerTest {

    private static WireMockServer mockedServer;
    private static HttpClient client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {

        mockedServer = new WireMockServer();
        mockedServer.start();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        mockedServer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_get_all_mock() {


        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/api/Payment"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json;charset=UTF-8")
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("")


                ));


        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/api/Payment");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            assert response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```